# Can the Mishnah be interpreted according to both peshat and drash?

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, mishna, vilna-gaon

There's a statement attributed to the Vilna Gaon (quoted in the introduction to [Binas Mikra](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46426&st=&pgnum=744) and in several other places) that the Mishnah can be interpreted according to 'peshat' which can sometimes differ from the Gemara's understanding of those Mishnayos, just as pesukim can have a 'peshat' which doesn't conform to halacha.

Are there other sources (besides for those quoting the Vilna Gaon) for such an idea, or anyone who explicitly refutes this position?

Comment: http://www.bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=2304477&forum_id=1364

Comment: http://www.ybm.org.il/hebrew/LessonArticle.aspx?item=5150

Comment: I don't know how I would relocate it, but I have a fuzzy memory about a Ya'avetz who makes this point.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for sources contemporaneous with the Vilna Gaon, or earlier?

Comment: Does he mean drash as in what mroll answered, a homiletic drash? Or does he mean drash like you answered, a halachic drasha? According to you when he says pshat, that means what we call pashut pshat when it comes to psukim. According to mroll pshat means real pshat, halacha limaaseh.

Comment: The footnote sound more like your approach, but that whole kabbalistic atzilus jargon wouldn't exclude mroll's. In fact, mroll's source of homiletic approach would at the very least be a kal vichomer to a simplistic reading approach.

Comment: @mevaqesh earlier, preferably

Comment: And I just noticed Kouty's answer is also assuming you are looking for sources for homiletic interpretations.

Comment: @user6591 I don't think that's a kal vachomer at all. It's very likely that Mishnayos are written with a level of ruach hakodesh or something which allows for drashos to be made out of them, but peshat is relevant to halacha. In other words, to assume that there's a different peshat than the Gemara is a pretty bold statement: the Gemara itself is apparently not the peshat (or at least the only peshat).

Comment: @Matt I disagree, but maybe. That wasn't my main point. A clarification of what we are actually looking for was the main part.

Comment: @user6591 oh, my mistake- I hadn't read the question in a while so I didn't notice how unclear it is. I edited to clarify what I was actually looking for

Answer (score 2):

Yes. **Tosfos Yom Tov** (Nazir 5:5) writes that just as earlier commentators were willing to explain the Torah according to a *peshat* that doesn't conform with the Halakha, we may do the same when it comes to the Mishnah (as long as we don't present it as being the halakha). More on this methodology is discussed by R. Kalman Kahane in *Heker VeYiyun* I, pg. 150-152

Additionally, there are also sources (Gra-related and otherwise) on a similar topic: The Netziv (Sheiltos Bamidbar 128) says דרך הגמרא לעקם פירוש המשנה כדי לאוקמה הלכה, the Gemara will distort the intended meaning of the Mishnaic text in order to have it conform to the Halakha. Such a position was likely influenced by writings of the Vilna Gaon's students, as this is explicitly stated in his name by his student, R. Baruch of Shklov, in his introduction to the Pe'as Hashulchan.

There are a few earlier sources for such an understanding, to give a few examples (out of many):

1. Ramban to Gitin 82a says that a particular position is that of the Amoraim alone who are 'hanging' it upon the mishnah
2. Rif (Brachos, Rif 24a) writes that he'd rather pasken the halakha according to the mishnah's simple reading than according to forced explanations in order to fit it with other opinions
3. The Meiri in his introduction to Maseches Avos refers to these odds methods of 'interpreting' Mishna as לחלוק עמהם בקצת דברים, and R. Havlin's footnote there connects his position to that of the Netziv

Comment: This gemara in Sota should not be forgotten. תנא התנאים מבלי עולם מבלי עולם ס''ד אמר רבינא שמורין הלכה מתוך משנתן תניא נמי הכי א''ר יהושע וכי מבלי עולם הן והלא מיישבי עולם הן שנאמר{חבקוק ג-ו} הליכות עולם לו אלא שמורין הלכה מתוך משנתן

Comment: This is what Tos. Y.T wrote: אע"פ שבגמרא לא פירשו כן. הואיל לענין דינא לא נפקא מינה ולא מידי. הרשות נתונה לפרש. שאין אני רואה הפרש בין פירוש המשנה לפירוש המקרא שהרשות נתונה לפרש במקראות כאשר עינינו הרואות חבורי הפירושים שמימות הגמ'. אלא שצריך שלא יכריע ויפרש שום דין שיהא סותר דעת בעלי הגמ':

Comment: Not exactly what is presented here.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all acharonim, particularly chassidim make
 this. The Toldot Yaakov Yossef quoted several times a mishna in kidushin concerning Yichud. Erllier,  Maharal interpreted in psacim זיתום המצרי ושכר המדי וחומץ האדומי...as an allusion to Galuyot.

**An entire book on Mishnayot called [Maasse Rokeach](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/23913)  is only drushim al pi Kabbalah on mishna.**

The introduction of the book addressed the link between Mishna and pardes.

Answer (score -1):

The Baal Hatanya most certainly does. On the Mishnah in shabbos that all animals that go out with collars... He explains it to be talking about angels and their song.